I'm updating my elementor website but it's not showing on the website
I've facing some issue with my website built on elementor pro page builder. When i update anything on the site it's not showing to the live site. It takes time to update the site to show on the live site. It's not updating instantly. Sometimes it takes 2-3 days to update on the live site and someitmes it doesn't update. Same problem is hapening with the global header and footer also. I'm updating but it's not showing on the site.
Some strange problem happening with the site. Also my header and footer is updated already for desktop but it's not showing for the mobile while i've already updated from the dashboard globally.
Can anyone give me the solution and let me know what and why this is happening? and what should i do for instant updating?
Thanks in advance everyone
I've set header footer globally but it didn't work. When i logged in and check everythings are fine but just not showing on the live site and it takes huge time to update sometime.

This happens mainly due to browser cache issues. While logged in, you will see changes but visitors will not see the updates.
To solve this, use a cache plugin like "Litespeed Cache" to purge cache.
Steps to Do so:

Go to Plugins, Search for Litespeed Cache
Click Install, then activate.
Refresh your page and you will see a flash icon on top.
Hover on it, and select Purge All Cache.

I hope it will solve your problem.

I've tried already but didn't worked.

Here are some tips from me:

Clear your browser's cache (How to clear the browser's cache?)
Regenerate Elementor files & data (Follow this steps)

You can also try checking in another browser or an incognito browser.
I hope this resolves your issue.

I've tried already this process also but didn't work.
